# How to configure Apache to use a PHP installation in the home directory of a non-root user?

Tags: linux, apache-http-server, php, webserver, home-directory

I compiled and installed PHP 7 as a non-root user (with the *--prefix=${HOME}/php* option) in his home directory on a Centos 6.8 server.

There exists also a working system installation of *Apache 2.2.15* and *PHP 5.4.45* but its configurations under /etc/ can only be modified by the root user of the server.

Is it possible to use this PHP installation without touching the configuration in */etc/httpd*? Maybe through a configuration with a *.htaccess* file?